# Insert Cursor Not Filling XY Field

Tags: arcpy, cursor, search

I have a table with a set of original XY values and a set of new XY values. I want to create new points of the new xy's using the insert cursor. My code updates the ID and Sp row but not the XY row.

```
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*Clip_1'):

  X = 'X1'
  Y = 'Y1'
  ID ='Sp'
  xy = []

  with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [X, Y, ID]) as Cursor:
    for row in Cursor:
        xy = [(row[2],(row[0],row[1]))]
        cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,['Sp','SHAPE@XY'])
        for new in xy:
            cursor.insertRow(new)
            print str(new)
  del row, xy
```

my output table looks like:

```
ID   Sp    X    Y    X1   Y1
1    21    25   25   21   19
2    22    12   29   12   18
3    23    14   18   22   10
4    21    
5    22    
6    23
```

What I want is

```
ID   Sp    X    Y    X1   Y1
1    21    25   25   21   19
2    22    12   29   12   18
3    23    14   18   22   10
4    21    21   19
5    22    12   18
6    23    22   10
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You use the variable name `row` twice.

Comment: Right whoops... that still did not affect the outcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The token `"SHAPE@XY"` populates the geometries of the feature. You won't see the results in your output table. If you have fields for `X` and `Y` use their names instead of `"SHAPE@XY"`.

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,['Sp','X', 'Y']) as iCurs:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [X, Y, ID]) as sCurs:
        for row in sCurs:
            row = (row[2],row[0],row[1])
            iCurs.insertRow (row)
```

If you want the geometries updated as well also include `"SHAPE@XY"` in your insert cursor.

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,['Sp','X', 'Y', "SHAPE@XY"]) as iCurs:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [X, Y, ID]) as sCurs:
        for row in sCurs:
            row = (row[2],row[0],row[1], (row[0],row[1]))
            iCurs.insertRow (row)
```

For your `RuntimeError` it sounds like you may have instances of X coordinates but not Y's or something along those lines, which I can see causing issues. Make sure that for each XY in your input table there are no null values.

Comment: worked great! except the RuntimeError, only occurs when it goes to the next file